# How to add custom options menu when Right Click on edit tool - Livecode

Tags: livecode

I want to create object and I want to add custom options menu when Right Click on edit tool.

This image :
[image]

I want to add custom menu on top "Edit Script"

How do I do ?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you really are asking. When you right-click on an object, the IDE throws up a menu because it invokes the command: revPopUpMenu. Try this, just put the command in a button script.

If you want to make this your own, without hacking the IDE menu, then why not use a normal click and show a pullDown menu instead. You can populate the menu items as you wish, including especially the ability to populate on the fly based on the object clicked on, or any other attributes that might be local to that object or event.

Craig Newman

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example to add to the IDE's context menu - originally posted on the livecode forums.  There's also an example stack you can download : http://forums.runrev.com/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=18613

```
# catch the IDE's context menu message
on revHookBuildObjectEditorContextMenu pMenuTarget, pMenuName, @pMenu, pModifiedMenu

   # custom menu item
   put "Custom Item" & "-" & LF before pMenu

   pass revHookBuildObjectEditorContextMenu
end revHookBuildObjectEditorContextMenu





# catch the IDE's message when an item is selected from the context menu
function dispatchContextMenuPick pMenuName, pItem

   switch word 1 to -1 of pItem

      case "Custom Item"
         answer "Custom Item Selected"
         exit to top
         break

   end switch

   pass dispatchContextMenuPick
end dispatchContextMenuPick
```

- To get it to work, put the code above into a button then use;

  insert the script of button "MyFrontScript" into front